# Commit changes to gridview from another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have form1 which include a gridview bound to the customer table and when user double clicks on the gridview row a new form2 shows up and let user to modify data. When user modifies data and clicks on save button in form2 then it saves changes to database, but changes do not appear in form1 gridview until form1 is reopened. Why?

```
//FORM1 when user double click on rows to edit 
private void radGridView1_CommandCellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridCommandCellElement gCommand = (sender as GridCommandCellElement);     
    string v = gCommand.RowInfo.Cells["CustomerID"].Value.ToString();
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(v);
    f2.Show(this);
}

//FORM2 when user click on save button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WindowsFormsApplication4TELERIK.Properties.Settings.Default.NorthwindConnectionString))
    {
       con.Open();
       using (SqlTransaction tran =con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
       {
          SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = "update customers set CompanyName='" + this.radTextBoxControl1.Text +"'";
          tran.Commit();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: bind the `gridview` again once u have updated the field.

Comment: I can't access to gridview from form2 !!!!@PraveenNambiar

Comment: looks like windows application...right?

Comment: check the answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not as straightforward as we think.

A simple way of doing this is mentioned in the below link. Just follow the steps mentioned in it.

[Refresh `GridView` from Form 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395624/how-to-refresh-datagridview-when-closing-child-form)

Comment: many many thanks ,but I have one more problem :
I don't want to fill table adapter bcoz it lost the modified record in grid !!! so let me know if there is solution