# how to refresh datagridview on parent form when child form closes

Tags: c#

i would like to know how to refresh my datagridview on frmClient automatically when frmUpdate which opens as .showDialog closes. i tried calling a refresh button click event in frmClient at frmUpdate form closing event and frmClient load but both didnt work.

```
      private void frmUpdate_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
    //     kryptonButton1_Click_1(null;null);
       frmClient_Load_1(null;null);
    }



  public void frmClient_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_clientgridview", connection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            kryptonDataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;



        }


    }
```

Comment: can you not null out the DataSource of the Parent then reassign it..?

Comment: how are you binding the data to the current datagridview...? perhaps showing more code I would be able to better assist.. also I am talking about Binding this is quite easy

Comment: I believe this post has the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395624/how-to-refresh-datagridview-when-closing-child-form?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Function to load the client.

```
private void LoadClient()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_clientgridview", connection);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        kryptonDataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
}

private void frmClient_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LoadClient();
}

//In Update button:
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  frmUpdate frm = new frmUpdate();
  frm.ShowDialog()
  //refresh the datagridview by call again the LoadClient();
  LoadClient();
}
```

That should do it :) Happy coding!

Comment: i get underlined error on LoadClient(); in frmUpdate which says it does not exist in context and moreover i dnt want to reload frmClient but refresh the datagrid when i call frmUpdate this.Close();

Comment: all this codes are only in frmClient.. this will not reload the frmClient but to refresh the data in datagrid view.

Comment: well i dnt open frmUpdate directly from .ShowDialog(); when its button is clicked, i rather call ` kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick` from button Update click like this  kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(null, null); which opens frmUpadate with selected datagrid row values in frmUpdate's textboxes, i thought u shoud know about that too

Comment: private void kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
           frmUpdate frm = new frmUpdate();
          frm.ShowDialog()
          frm.Textbox1.text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
          //refresh the datagridview by call again the LoadClient();
          LoadClient();
        }

Comment: tanx it finally worked, i used your process as reference and did modification in my process and it did exactly what i intend it to do +10 for you. i'll post my whole process as a reference to someone else in future

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to call the refresh function to update the datagridview

```
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_clientgridview", connection);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        kryptonDataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
        kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        kryptonDataGridView1.Refresh(); //This or below will work
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok as reference to Mark's code i created a LoadClient(); function

```
  private void LoadClient()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_clientgridview", connection);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            kryptonDataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            kryptonDataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

and in my kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick event method i changed f2.Show(); to   f2.ShowDialog(); and i called my LoadClient(); here instead of frmClient_Load_1 method as you can see below.

```
  private void kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            frmUpdate f2 = new frmUpdate();


            f2.lblClientID.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ClientID"].Value.ToString();
            f2.lblClearinAgentID.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Clearing_Agent_ID"].Value.ToString();
            f2.textboxClientCode.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Client Code"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxClientName.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Client Name"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxPostalAddress.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Postal Address"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxTelephone.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Telephone"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxFax.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Fax"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress1.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 1"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress2.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 2"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxEmailAddress3.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["E-mail Address 3"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxWebsite.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Website"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxChargeRate.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Charge Rate"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxTotalDepo.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Total Deposit"].Value.ToString();
            f2.txtboxAccountBal.Text = kryptonDataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Account Balance"].Value.ToString();

            f2.ShowDialog();

            LoadClient();
        }
```

then in my Update button click event, i called kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick method explicitly

```
  private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       kryptonDataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(null, null);

    }
```