# Refresh Datagrid When Dialog Form Closed

Tags: c#

I have an application like this:

- There's one main form (frmMasuk) with datagrid and "Add New" button
- When someone clicks Add New, it shows the dialog form (Form2) to add new data.
- When someone clicks "Save" on dialog form, it will be closed and
  the datagrid will be refreshed

I got a problem when the dialog form closes, the datagrid must be refreshed.

This is some of my code:

frmMasuk:

```
public frmMasuk()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kas ORDER BY id_kas, tanggal DESC", koneksi.mykonek);
        koneksi.openkonek();
        SqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable a = new DataTable();
        a.Load(reader);
        koneksi.closekonek();
        dgv.DataSource = a;
        dgv.Enabled = true;

    }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmKasNew a = new frmKasNew();
            a.ShowDialog();
        }
```

frmKasNew:

```
 private void simpankas()
        {
            koneksi.openkonek();
            DateTime tgl = Convert.ToDateTime(ttanggal.Text);
            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO kas(tanggal, jenis, jumlah,  keterangan) VALUES('"+ tgl +"','"+ tjenis.Text +"','" + tjumlah.Text +  "','" + tket.Text  +"') ",koneksi.mykonek);
            int exe = sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (exe == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data gagal disimpan ke database", "Aplikasi KAS Usaha", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil disimpan!", "Aplikasi KAS Usaha", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Dispose();


            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ttanggal.Text == "" || tjenis.Text == "" || tjumlah.Text == "" || tket.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Harap melengkapi data sebelum menyimpan","Aplikasi KAS Usaha",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                simpankas();
            }
            // end if
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh datagridview when closing child form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395624/how-to-refresh-datagridview-when-closing-child-form)

Comment: but i got a problem in:
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmKasNew a = new frmKasNew(this);
            a.ShowDialog();
        }
..

message:
does not contain a cunstructor that take 1 arguments

Comment: you forgot this part in the child form     Form1 _owner;
    public Form2(Form1 owner) {
        _owner = owner;
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form2_FormClosing);
    }
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        _owner.PerformRefresh();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event to the a.OnClose event:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmKasNew a = new frmKasNew();
        a.FormClosed += FormClosed;
        a.ShowDialog();
    }

private void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM kas ORDER BY id_kas, tanggal DESC", koneksi.mykonek);
        koneksi.openkonek();
        SqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable a = new DataTable();
        a.Load(reader);
        koneksi.closekonek();
        dgv.DataSource = a;
        dgv.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: where i must place "a.FormClosed += FormClosed;" ? and where i must place private void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) ?

Comment: try DataSource = null; DataSource = a;

Comment: i also add "enviroment.exit();" it also not take an effect. everyting under FormClosed(....) not take an effect

Comment: Does the function get called ? Is the code to refresh the data correct ?

Comment: Also, I messed up the code put the **a.FormClosed += FormClosed;** BEFORE **a.ShowDialog();** I fixed the code in the answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried showing the form with a DialogResult like

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
frmKasNew kas = new frmKasNew();
DialogResult result = kas.ShowDialog():

If (result == DialogReult.OK)
{
    CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)
    dgv.BindingContext[a];
    cm.Refresh();
}
```

Then use CurrencyManager to to refresh the datagrid?